# Scipy installation issue, getting ImportError: libopenblas.so.0: cannot open shared object file or directory

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, openblas

I am installing `Scipy-0.16.1` on `Ubuntu 14.04`

`OpenBLAS_0.2.18` and `Numpy-1.11.0` have been installed with no issues.

`Scipy-0.16.1.tar.gz` has been downloaded

`site.cfg` was copied and un-commented the following lines:

```
[openblas]

libraries = openblas

library_dirs = /opt/OpenBLAS/lib

include_dirs = /opt/OpenBLAS/include
```

Added a line to `~/.bashrc`

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/OpenBLAS/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

source ~/.bashrc

ldconfig

sudo python setup.py config

**ERROR**

> ImportError: libopenblas.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such
>   file or directory

Answer (score 32):

You have to install `OpenBlas` system library. Try:

```
sudo apt-get install libopenblas-dev
```

Comment: try `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before run setup.py

Comment: or you can try to install scipy with `pip install scipy==0.16.1`

Comment: I tried export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH and run sudo python setup.py config , it still shows same error

Comment: try to install with pip

Comment: I tried   pip install scipy and get Requirement already satisfied (use  --upgrad to upgrade): script in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Comment: it seems that you already have scipy installed. try to open a python shell and try `import scipy`

Comment: In centos use: `dnf install openblas-devel`

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, try `locate libopenblas.so.0` to find out the path.

Then, do `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to check if it has been included.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and I have scipy on 1.2.1. This causes the error above.

The reason is scipy 1.2.1 looks for libopenblas.so.0. But, Ubuntu 20.04 APT repo libraries will only support libopenblas.so.

So, my solution was to upgrade scipy to 1.4.0 or above.